# Value of $\int_{-1}^{t} (1.5-2|x|)\,dx$

Tags: integration, absolute-value

What is the value of $$\int_{-1}^{t} \left(\frac{3}{2} - 2 \, |x| \right) \,dx? $$ I get confused integrating with the absolute value.

I forgot to mention $t>0$.

Comment: You need to split it to a sum of two integrals then. $|x|=x$ when $x\geq 0$, $|x|=-x$ when $x<0$.

Comment: So then there would be one integral from -1 to 0 added to the integral from 0 to t?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to solve it.

Comment: Note that you only split it if $t>0$. If $t\leq0$, you can replace $|x|$ by $(-x)$ and just do the integration.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The only way to integrate an expression involving $|x|$ is to break it into integrals over intervals where $x$ is positive and where it is negative, then replace $|x|$ by $x$ in the first case and by $(-x)$ in the second.